# Space in the middle of the table

Tags: tables, spacing

how can I put tabular space to a text in a row?

Here is the code that Im trying to change.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{
>{\columncolor[HTML]{D0D0D0}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{ECECEC}}l }
\cellcolor[HTML]{343434}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} CU-01} & \cellcolor[HTML] 
{D0D0D0}\textbf{Gesto puntual}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
\\
Descripción                                          & \begin{tabular}[c] 
{@{}l@{}}El jugador presiona en la pantalla para seleccionar un lugar al que 
el personaje \\ principal debe dirigirse.\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
\\
\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Actores                      & \cellcolor[HTML] 
{F4F4F4}Jugador                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
\\
Precondiciones                                       & \begin{tabular}[c] 
{@{}l@{}}1. El jugador se encuentra en la pantalla de juego.\\ 2. El juego de 
un nivel está en curso.\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
\\
\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Flujo                        & \cellcolor[HTML] 
{F4F4F4}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. SI el jugador presiona en un lugar de 
la 
pantalla a la que el personaje principal \\ se pueda dirigir.\\      1.2 El 
personaje principal se dirige al lugar.\\ 2. SI NO, SI el jugador presiona en 
un lugar de la pantalla a la que el personaje no \\ puede dirigir.\\      2.1 
El jugador no se dirige hacia esa posición.\\ 3  FIN SI.\end{tabular} \\
Poscondiciones                                       & \begin{tabular}[c] 
{@{}l@{}}1. El personaje principal llega sin problemas hasta el lugar 
indicado 
o se queda \\ en su posición\end{tabular}  \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caso de uso:CU-01: Gesto puntual}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is the result of my code:

[image: Result of the code]

And this example of internet is what I want but with my points "1." and "1.2" for example. How can I do that because I tried to put blank spaces but it didn't work to me.

[image: That's is what I really want but with the points 1. and 1.2]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Try `\hspace*{0.5cm}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to  allow for automated indentation, I would suggest to use an `enumerate`-like environment. In the following MWE, I have also used `tabularx` in order to automatically fit the table into the textwidth instead of inserting manual linebreaks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenumi}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[tabenumi]{wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin= * }
\setlist[tabenumi, 1]{label=\arabic*.,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}}
\setlist[tabenumi, 2]{label*=\arabic*.}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
>{\columncolor[HTML]{D0D0D0}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{ECECEC}}X }
\cellcolor[HTML]{343434}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} CU-01} & \cellcolor[HTML] 
{D0D0D0}\textbf{Gesto puntual}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
\\
Descripción                                          & El jugador presiona en la pantalla para seleccionar un lugar al que el personaje  principal debe dirigirse.
\\
\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Actores                      & \cellcolor[HTML] {F4F4F4}Jugador                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
\\
Precondiciones                                       & \begin{tabenumi} 
                                                       \item El jugador se encuentra en la pantalla de juego. 
                                                       \item El juego de un nivel está en curso.
                                                       \end{tabenumi}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
\\
\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Flujo                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{F4F4F4}\begin{tabenumi}
                                                       \item SI el jugador presiona en un lugar de la pantalla a la que el personaje principal  se pueda dirigir.
                                                        \begin{tabenumi}
                                                          \item[1.2.] El personaje principal se dirige al lugar.
                                                        \end{tabenumi}
                                                        \item SI NO, SI el jugador presiona en un lugar de la pantalla a la que el personaje no puede dirigir.
                                                        \begin{tabenumi}
                                                          \item El jugador no se dirige hacia esa posición.
                                                        \end{tabenumi}
                                                        \item   FIN SI.
                                                        \end{tabenumi} \\
Poscondiciones                                       &  \begin{tabenumi}
                                                          \item  El personaje principal llega sin problemas hasta el lugar indicado o se queda en su posición
                                                         \end{tabenumi}  \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Caso de uso:CU-01: Gesto puntual}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]